# How to fix the value of a variable LUA

Tags: lua

I'm a little doubt, I think it is easy to solve, but I do not know ...

I'm needing to save the value of a scene to another, in a game.

For example: the player is playing, and the money variable increases, this value would stay for all scenes, which is what I want. However its value is supposedly being wiped when I enter the main menu, as if it has never existed...

Can someone tell me how to set value for all my scenes?

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to help you out.

Comment: Yeah, we need the actual code, before we can even start helping you out. I've attempted an answer though, but there's too little information to tell whether it is what you're after.

Comment: You use Corona, I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you declaring your variable as a `local`?
For example, is the beginning of your function similar to this?:

```
local gamescore = score;
```

If so, you'll need to remove the `local`, like so:

```
gamescore = score;
```

This is because the `local` definition only declares variables in the *local* block of code that it resides (i.e, it cannot be called anywhere else).
For example, if I had this function:

```
function = Test(score)
    local sc = 0+score;
    return sc;
end
```

The variable `sc` wouldn't be available anywhere else, apart from inside this function, whilst:

```
function = Test(score)
    sc = 0+score;
    return sc;
end
```

this `sc` would, as it is not `local` to that specific function.

Don't use `local` if you want your variable to be used elsewhere, *but be careful that you don't overwrite it in some other function*, it's easy to do, as I've done it myself a few times.